# Reactjs: remove input tag value with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

When I click the button, the function **createPost** works and my data goes to the server properly. but the input value doesn't remove.

```
//...existing code...
createPost=()=>{
        var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapi/createpost/'
        fetch(url,{
            method:'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Token '+this.props.token,    
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({
                'body':this.state.body
            })
        })
        .then((response)=>{
            response.json()
            document.getElementById("asif").value=''
            this.setState({body:''})
            this.props.rerender()
        })
    }
//...code...
<div className="rest container">
                        <p>
                        <input id="asif" onChange={(e)=>{this.setState({body:e.target.value})}}
                        style={{width:'100%', height:'36px', borderRadius:'25px'}}
                        placeholder={"What's on your mind, "+this.props.userdata.firstname+"?"} />
                        </p>
                        
                    </div>
//...code
```

I wrote the almost same code in another component and it works. but what is the problem here in my code?

Comment: Add `value` attribute on the `input` element: `<input ... value={this.state.body}/>`

Comment: Thank you Yousaf. May Allah help you